# Javascript Array.sort() not finishing before next action starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So i need to sort a string array in alphabetical order and then print it in a file. The sorting works great but sometimes,most times, the file i output is empty but when I put a breakpoint just before the writing, its always full. Is there a way to make surethat an action is executed after one has ended. Here's a fix i did that works 4/5 times.

```
var noms=function(){
var sys = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs'),
lineReader = require('readline'),
names=[];

var reader = lineReader.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('text_files/prenoms.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    console: false
});
reader.on('line', function(line) {
    if(getVowels(line)%2==0){
        names.push(line);

    }
});
setTimeout(()=>{
    names=names.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a < b) return -1;
        else if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
})
setTimeout(()=>{
    names=names.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a < b) return -1;
        else if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('text_files/sortie.txt');
    names.forEach(function(line){
        file.write(line+",\n");
    });
    file.end();
    exec(getCommandLine() + ' ' + 'text_files/sortie.txt');
},0)


}
function getVowels(line) {
    var m = line.match(/[aeiouy]/gi);
    return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
  }
  function getCommandLine() {
    switch (process.platform) { 
       case 'darwin' : return 'open';
       case 'win32' : return 'start';
       case 'win64' : return 'start';
       default : return 'xdg-open';
    }
 }
```

Comment: The `.sort()` function is synchronous. The sorting process is always finished when the function returns. Your problem is that the file reading process is **asynchronous**, and may not be finished when your timers go off.

Comment: Okay ! and is there a way to make it synchronous or to put the rest of the process in a callback function executed when the reading proccess is done ? Also i guess the writing process will be async too

Comment: Add a handler for the "close" event, and do your sorting etc in there.